# Масштабирование камеры и слежение за объектом, анимация

Tags: unity3d

Не могу придумать реализацию для задачи:

допустим есть два объекта UI, прямоугольник и квадрат, необходимо масштабировать камеру на прямоугольнике, примерно 60%, затем этот прямоугольник движется к квадрату, все еще с масштабом 60%, как только прямоугольник достигнет позиции квадрата масштабирование плавно возвращается в норму.

режим `Canvas Render mode = Screen Space Camera`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими способами это можно реализовать?

CinemaMachine не рассматриваю, потому что апк должен быть не более 10МБ

Comment: Сколько не пытался, так и не понял, что вы хотите получить, поясните подробнее. Более того, как вы хотите "зумить, концентрируя камеру на прямоугольнике", если у вас положение прямоугольника зависит от положения камеры, а не наоборот? Тут либо менять размер + положение самих UI элементов, что бред и мазахизм, либо использовать другой режим отрисовки канваса. Без пояснения желаемого результата не могу подсказать больше.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы нацелиться на предмет используйте метод [Transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).

Для расчета сколько объект занимает на экране и подгонки пирамиды видимости можно воспользоваться [формулами из документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html).

Ну а чтобы камера плавно двигалась за объектом придется делать интерполяцию, что-то типа такого:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowMe : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform TargetMove = null;
public bool Smoothing = true;

public float TimeMoving = 0.5f;

public float minDistance = 0.1f;

public float minAngle = 0.2f;
public Vector3 MoveMask = Vector3.one;
public Vector3 RotateMask = Vector3.one;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (TargetMove != null)
    {
        if (Smoothing)
        {
            float sqrDistance = (TargetMove.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
            float angle = Quaternion.Angle(TargetMove.rotation, transform.rotation);
            UpdatePosition(sqrDistance > minDistance * minDistance ? Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, TargetMove.position, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving) : TargetMove.position);
            UpdateRotation(angle > minAngle ? Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, TargetMove.rotation, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving).eulerAngles : TargetMove.eulerAngles);
        }
        else
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }
}

public void Reset()
{
    UpdatePosition(TargetMove.position);
    UpdateRotation(TargetMove.eulerAngles);
}

void UpdatePosition(Vector3 position)
{
    Vector3 old = transform.position;
    transform.position = new Vector3(old.x * (1 - MoveMask.x) + position.x * MoveMask.x, old.y * (1 - MoveMask.y)+position.y* MoveMask.y, old.z * (1 - MoveMask.z) + position.z * MoveMask.z );
}

void UpdateRotation(Vector3 rotation)
{
    Vector3 old = transform.eulerAngles;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(old.x * (1 - RotateMask.x) + rotation.x * RotateMask.x, old.y * (1 - RotateMask.y) + rotation.y * RotateMask.y, old.z * (1 - RotateMask.z) + rotation.z * RotateMask.z);

}
}
```